# JunOS SCU (source class) matching not working on vMX 18

Tags: juniper, junos

I testing Junos Subscriber Manager on virtual playgroung.
All seems fine and work as expected on real hardware. But with dynamic profile with source-class sclass_mytest option not working.

If I disable only one line "source-class sclass_mytest" all becomes normal and client receives IP address with applied dynamic profile.

With source-class sclass_mytest client doesn't get IP address at all - because of profile problems.

Does anyone know how to debug profiles and see in logs errors/warning?

Dynamic profile config excerpt:

```
firewall {
    family inet {                       
        filter "$inet_in" {
            interface-specific;
            term service {
                from {
                    service-filter-hit;
                }
                then accept;
            }
            term First{
                from {
                    source-class sclass_mytest;
                }
                then {
                    policer "$policer_in";
                    service-accounting;
                    service-filter-hit;
                    accept;
                }
            }
            term Last{                
                then accept;
            }
        }
    }
...
```

Looks like source class has mark in routing table:

All prefixes with communities: 7:1  are marked with sclass_mytest

```
inet.0: 29 destinations, 29 routes (29 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
1.0.4.0/22 (1 entry, 1 announced)
TSI:
KRT in-kernel 1.0.4.0/22 -> {50.0.0.1}
Source class: sclass_mytest
        *BGP    Preference: 170/-191
                Next hop type: Router, Next hop index: 662
                Address: 0xc808710
                Next-hop reference count: 48
                Source: 50.0.0.1
                Next hop: 50.0.0.1 via ae0.100, selected
                Session Id: 0x142
                State: <Secondary Active Ext>
                Peer AS:  123456
                Age: 14:16      Metric: 0 
                Validation State: unverified 
                Task: BGP_123456_789.50.0.0.1
                Announcement bits (1): 0-KRT 
                AS path: 123456 I
                Communities: 7:1
                Accepted
                Localpref: 195
                Router ID: 2.21.89.1    
                Primary Routing Table testrt.inet.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like vMX doesn't support SCU at all.
For example real MX 16.X works good but eval image even doesn't have such option at all.
vMX 18 has such configuration parameter but it's only consumes space in config.